# Blob size to be set

Tags: opencv, openvino, python

Input blob size is not equal network input size

Square root of required network input size was the plan, not tried.

cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2-openvino_2018_R2.0.0) /home/jenkins/workspace/OpenCV/OpenVINO/build/opencv/modules/dnn/src/op_inf_engine.cpp:416: error: (-215:Assertion failed) Failed to initialize Inference Engine backend: Input blob size is not equal network input size (50176!=150528). in function 'initPlugin'

Should not give the above error

Comment: Are you able to update the version of OpenVINO? 2018 R2 seems pretty old. If no, check an input shape at `.xml` file and make sure your input blob has the same.

Comment: thanks mitry, I managed by resizing the input image before the above operation.

Comment: So the problem is solved or you mean even with proper input blob shape you faced this error? If so, may I ask you to provide a reproducer?